# Nginx black ip module and databse

Tags: nginx

It is necessary to block some IP addresses from which ddos attacks or other nginx tools are carried out.
Is there any solution to block IP addresses from the blacklist that can be obtained somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Fail2Ban, CrowdSec, ModSecurity.
You should also attempt to [harden your TCP/IP stack](https://cromwell-intl.com/cybersecurity/stack-hardening.html) and optionally tweak your firewall - https://javapipe.com/blog/iptables-ddos-protection/

Comment: CrowdSec is very good! Thanks!